# Anybody know why this doesn't work if its writen like the react navigation docs?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

This is the btn that 'controls' the navigation.

It loads the first Stack, Home, but when I press the touchable opacity to go QnScreen it drops an error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate').

I try it all, I'm falling into depression lol.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";

export default function DocCard( { navigation } ){

   return(
      <TouchableOpacity 
         style={styles.container}
         onPress={()=>{
            navigation.navigate('QnScreen')
         }}
      >
         <LinearGradient
         style={styles.linearGradient}
            colors={['#4822E4','transparent']}
            start={{x:0, y:0}}
            end={{x:1, y:1}}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Create new Doc.</Text>
            <Image
               style={styles.icon}
               source={require('../../img/HomeScreen/doc_icon.png')}
            />
         </LinearGradient>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   );
}
```

And this is the `MainStack`:

```
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import QnScreen from '../screens/QnScreen';
import Home from '../screens/Home';
import React from 'react';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();


export default function MainStack(){
   return(
      <NavigationContainer>
         <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
               headerShown: false
            }}
         >
            <Stack.Screen
               name='Home'
               component={Home}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
               name='QnScreen'
               component={QnScreen}
            />   
         </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
   );
}
```

I'm using Expo with typescript

Comment: You need to show the code where you use the `<DocCard>` component and how you explicitly pass in a navigation object that implements a navigate method.

Comment: The first code is the ```<DocCard>``` component

Comment: Please show the code that uses your `DocCard` component, ie the code with `import DocCard from "..."` and `<DocCard ... />`

Answer (score -1):

First off, you'll need to have that navigation.navigate() call include a parameter that states which screen/screen-stack you want to navigate to. It doesn't look like that's your main issue though.

I can't tell from just the code you've posted, but judging from the 'navigation' object being undefined, it's most likely that your **DocCard** component is not a child of your Navigator. Where is **DocCard** in your component tree? Is it inside **QnScreen** or **Home**? Cause that's where it should be.

Then you'll need to receive the 'navigation' prop from one of your screens. And pass it as a prop to DocCard to be used. 'Navigation' and 'route' props are only automatically passed to screens.

Comment: My **DocCard** component is inside the Home Sceen. Wait, I try to explain my "structure". I have two screens, Home and QnScreen. At Home screen there are three components,, DocCard, InfEstCard, and ComoFuncCard. All are the same, a touchable opacity with a text and an image, and I want that when you press DocCard it charges the QnScreen, and the other cards the same but with other Screens

Comment: In that case your problem is that you need to pass the 'navigation' object from your screen to your component. Specifically that 'HomeScreen' will automatically receive 'navigation' prop, and then you should pass it as a prop to DocCard to be used.

Your useNavigation method works perfectly fine as well. But I figure you'd still want to know the reason for your issue before.

Answer (score -2):

I solve it!!!

The solution was using the useNavigation hook inside the component.

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";

export default function DocCard(){
   const navigation = useNavigation();
   return(
      <TouchableOpacity
         style={styles.container}
         onPress={()=>{
            navigation.navigate('QnScreen');
         }}
      >
         <LinearGradient
         style={styles.linearGradient}
            colors={['#4822E4','transparent']}
            start={{x:0, y:0}}
            end={{x:1, y:1}}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Crear nuevo documento de consentimiento informado.</Text>
            <Image
               style={styles.icon}
               source={require('../../img/HomeScreen/doc_icon.png')}
            />
         </LinearGradient>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   );
}
```

If anybody have this problem, there's the solution:)